# SQL Free space management

Tags: sql-server

I have 1.8TB AX database.

File Size : 1851427.75 MB

Free Space : 502837.13 MB

If free spaces will be used in the future, I don't want to shrink. Because it's taking a long time. (and index fragmentation)

Daily observations result:

1. Day Free space 492.435,75 MB (26%)
2. Day Free space 485.750,25 MB (26%)
3. Day Free space 502.875,75 MB (27%)

Sometimes the free space is reduced, sometimes data file size grows.

Why there is growth when there is free space, how SQL decides?

Comment: Do you have multiple filegroups? Do you have multiple files?

Comment: I have one filegroups, data file and log file.

Comment: Do you have a heap table that you truncate and load? Or delete from and load? It's possible that pages are not being deallocated from it.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, file growth consist of adding substantial extra space at once to the data file (making the file larger) when all the space is used.  So if the file has 9% free space then it may have just been full and then grown by 10%.  With a text comparing tool (Windows "fc" may do), a crude way to identify tables which are growing is to run "DBCC CHECKDB(N'name')" on different dates, save the output, and compare it.  There might be data getting added that you've overlooked.

Comment: I know the reason for the free space (deleting data). Why data file growing when I have free space? How can I prevent this?

Comment: @Lyns you can cap the size of the file in the Properties>>Files page of the db.  But keep an eye on it.   Or turn off autogrow in the same place.  Or both.   If it runs out of space when you arent looking, DML statements will fail.

Comment: @Kevin3NF If I close the growth, will sql server use the free space? If it needs to grow, what are do sql server?

Comment: @Lyns - capping the growth will stop the physical file from growing anymore.  Data will still be added until all allocated space is used, then you get an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server [tracks free space within data files](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175195.aspx) and uses that when additional space is needed. Data files will grow only when there is not enough existing free space to satisfy allocation needs.  Shrinking is not necessary for this space to be reused and should be generally be avoided for the reasons you mentioned.

If you observe occasional file growth even though sufficient free space exists, this may be due to short term space needs. For example, rebuilding a clustered index will require about 120% of the table size as free space during the operation that is freed afterward.

Comment: I have 700 GB table, but I don't rebuild. What reason else is grow data file? Is there anything I can do to keep the file from growing?

Comment: @Lyns, you could create an Extended Events trace to capture the database_file_size_changed event along with contextual information to identify the culprit.